# Align items on extremes with CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to align these boxes on the extremes (left and right). I am using mainly CSS Grid.

The boxes on the left are already naturally aligned, but the ones on the right are aligned to the start.

```css
.Container {
    background-color:yellow;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto minmax(373px, 906px) auto;
}

.Div {
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: minmax(272px, 372px) minmax(272px, 372px);
    max-width:906px;
    justify-content:center;
    grid-row-gap: 32px;
    background-color:yellow;
    grid-column: 2/3;
}

.Type {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div class="Div">
    <div class="Type">
    
    </div>
    <div class="Type">
    
    </div>
    <div class="Type">
    
    </div>
    <div class="Type">
    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to do it with CSS Grid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```css
.Container {
    background-color:yellow;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto minmax(373px, 906px) auto;
}

.Div {
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, max-content);
    width:100%;
    justify-content:space-between;
    grid-row-gap: 32px;
    background-color:yellow;
    grid-column: 2/3;
}

.Type {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div class="Div">
    <div class="Type">
    
    </div>
    <div class="Type">
    
    </div>
    <div class="Type">
    
    </div>
    <div class="Type">
    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.Container {
    background-color:yellow;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.Div {
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: minmax(272px, 372px) minmax(272px, 372px);
    max-width:906px;
    justify-content:center;
    background-color:yellow;
    grid-column: 2/3;
}

.Type {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:red;
}

.Type:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div class="Div-left">
    <div class="Type">
    
    </div>
    <div class="Type">
    
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Div-right">
    <div class="Type">
    
    </div>
    <div class="Type">
    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is this what you are looking for? If so, flexbox is great for this kind of alignment.

Answer (score 1):

You can select every 2n boxes and reset `margin`(first snippet) or  `justify-self`(second snippet).

Some reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Box_Alignment_in_CSS_Grid_Layout

```css
.Container {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto minmax(373px, 906px) auto;
}

.Div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(272px, 372px) minmax(272px, 372px);
  max-width: 906px;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-row-gap: 32px;
  background-color: yellow;
  grid-column: 2/3;
}

.Type {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.Type:nth-child(2n) {
  margin-left: auto
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div class="Div">
    <div class="Type">

    </div>
    <div class="Type">

    </div>
    <div class="Type">

    </div>
    <div class="Type">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.Container {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto minmax(373px, 906px) auto;
}

.Div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(272px, 372px) minmax(272px, 372px);
  max-width: 906px;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-row-gap: 32px;
  background-color: yellow;
  grid-column: 2/3;
}

.Type {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.Type:nth-child(2n) {
  justify-self: end;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div class="Div">
    <div class="Type">

    </div>
    <div class="Type">

    </div>
    <div class="Type">

    </div>
    <div class="Type">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```